# How to refresh to home page after alert clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

If the user cannot be found, I want to be able to show them an error message and return them to the home page after they click ok.

```
if (userID == -1)
{                               
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Account not recognised.')", true);
    Response.Redirect("AboutForm.aspx");
}
```

I expected to see the alert pop up and be able to click on it, then be redirected to the home page. However, my actual result skips past the alert and brings me back to the home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alert command is a javascript client blocking operation, your code don't work.
You can try to redirect the page via javascript code after the alert command, then, after the user clicked on ok button of the alert popup the next js code execute and redirect the browser page.

```
if (userID == -1)
{                               
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "usernotfound", "alert('Account not recognised.'); document.location.href='AboutForm.aspx';", true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're redirecting after registering the client script block. 
When you redirect it wipes the data for this page and starts 'fresh', ***meaning your script registration never transfers with a redirect***.

Remove the redirect is the solution. Alternatively, if you need to redirect to another page, you'd need to include some kind of query string onto the url with the message that you can capture on `Page_Load` of `AboutForm.aspx` and register the client script there.

An example for the latter:

```
if (userID == -1)
{                               

    Response.Redirect("AboutForm.aspx?showError=true");
}
```

and in `AboutForm.aspx`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Request.QueryString.Contains("showError") && Request.QueryString["showError"].ToLowerCase() == "true")
    {

        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Account not recognised.')", true);
    }
}
```